# Dilemma about React Hooks and AJAX call triggered by user by clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing a dilemma on how to properly implement the following *(basic)* functionality.

I have a simple React component with a button, when the user presses the button, an AJAX call is triggered to a REST server and then the result is shown to the user.

My component is something similar to the following:

```
function MainComponent() {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    async function getData() {
        const response = await fetch(...);
        setData(response);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button type="button" onClick={getData} />
            <div>
                {data}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I would like to add a loading spinner since the `fectch` call can take a while and here is when the doubts start. How do I handle properly the visibility state of the loading spinner?

```
function MainComponent() {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    async function getData() {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const response = await fetch(...);
        setIsLoading(false);
        setData(response);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button type="button" onClick={getData} />
            { isLoading ?
                    <span>Loading...</span>
                :
                    null
            }
            <div>
                {data}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Something like the code above works, but I have the feeling that it's not correct.

The second call to `setIsLoading`, the one after waiting for the `fetch` request to end, as far as I understood, should not work (but it does).

Let me explain why I think it should **not** work:

1. Render the component
2. User presses the button, the call `setIsLoading(true)` is done and at some point it will trigger a re-render.
3. That re-render happens, the "pointer" to the function `setIsLoading` should (or maybe not) change because the `useState` hook is called again due to the re-render
4. The call to `setIsLoading(false)` after the fetch (but also the one to `setData`) should affect an already old version of the component

Am I wrong? If yes, why? If my understanding of React Hooks is correct, how do I implement this simple use case in a proper way? (Maybe with an `useEffect`?)

Thank you very much

**EDIT:**

@Brad Ball proposed to use useEffect, but the problem of a re-render n between the function execution still persists. **How am I sure that the re-render after `setIsLoading(true);` keeps all the pointers to the functions correct?** And why and how is it different from the previous call?

```
function MainComponent() {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    const [request, setRequest] = useState(undefined);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, [request]);

    async function fetchData() {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const response = await fetch(request.url, ...);
        setIsLoading(false);
        setData(response);
    }

    function getData() {
        setRequest({
            url: '...',
            body: '...'
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button type="button" onClick={getData} />
            { isLoading ?
                    <span>Loading...</span>
                :
                    null
            }
            <div>
                {data}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**EDIT 2**:

Thanks for the answer: the problem is not coding it, it's on how to do it properly. How do I deal with multiple `setState` in an async function, so a re-render is triggered while the function is still running? Mine was only an example of an use case

Comment: put `{data}` where you put `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine. Using `useState` ensures that your component references the correct values and setters when they're called.

In terms of worrying about the exact order of re-renders etc, you shouldn't be concerned about what is rendering when. React code should be declaritive - your code describes what the end result should be, not how to get there. In terms of your specific case and concerns, the timing of re-renders is out of your control as state updates (and possible re-renders) are batched for optimisation purposes.

[Dan Abramov](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10231#issuecomment-316644950) had this to say about multple `setState` calls:

> In current release, they will be batched together if you are inside a React event handler. React batches all setStates done during a React event handler, and applies them just before exiting its own browser event handler.

I assume something similar applies to the hooks case but don't know this for sure.

Comment: My concern is about the fact that I call `setIsLoading(true);`, then await for a couple of seconds while in the meantime a re-render is performed and then I call `setIsLoading(true);` again in the same function that is actually owned by a component now overwritten by a re-render. Is it still fine? Where is this addressed in the documentation? I cannot find anything about it

Comment: as `setIsLoading` uses the `useState` Hook, this 'owning' problem is taken care of for you. This is a really good in-depth dive by Dan Abramov: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/  (it helps with much more than just `useEffect`)

Comment: in other words... `useState` means that (pretty much) you can think of your state being 'contained' in a functional component like you would have previously thought of it in a class component.

Comment: I read the article and it has been very useful. I shed light on a lot of use cases, but also that React guarantees that some function are stable during each re-render. I then looked at the docs and it says: *"React guarantees that setState function identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders."*. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `useEffect` hook. It is built in for these reasons. it is similar to `componentDidMount` in classes

[Link to docs here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: Thank you, see my edit please. The main problem still persists, I would like to understand how and why the `setState` called in-between a function called from an `useEffect` is different from one called from a normal function

Answer (score 0):

You need to use conditional rendering,

```
return (
        <div>
            <button type="button" onClick={getData} />
            { isLoading ?
                    <span>Loading...</span>
                :
                <div>
                  {data}
                </div>
            }            
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: See EDIT 1 and EDIT 2 please. Your answer doesn't answer to my question and in addition hides the previously loaded data in case the user presses the button more than one time